MUI TextField number type min max not working
Material UI version: "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
Here's the snippet code
<TextField
 className="input-quantity form-input"
 defaultValue={0}
 name={"quantity"}
 type="number"
 InputProps={{
    inputProps: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
    },
 }}
 onChange={(event: any) =>
    handleChange(e)
 }
/>

the input still can pass over 100, even to thousand value.
this happened to text type too as the inputProps used maxLength

<TextField
  className="input-quantity form-input"
  defaultValue={0}
  name="quantity"
  type="number"
  InputProps={{
    inputProps: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
    },
  }}
  onChange={(event: any) => handleChange(event)}
  onInput={(e) => {
    const numericValue = parseFloat(e.target.value);

    // Check if the numeric value exceeds the max value (100)
    if (!isNaN(numericValue) && numericValue > 100) {
      e.target.value = "100";
    }

    // Check if the numeric value is below the min value (0)
    if (!isNaN(numericValue) && numericValue < 0) {
      e.target.value = "0";
    }
  }}
/>


InputProps properties are handled in Material-UI's  component.
Users can still enter values outside the specified range
You can try something like that:
  const YourComponent = () => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value >= 0 && value <= 100) {
      setQuantity(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      className="input-quantity form-input"
      value={quantity}
      name="quantity"
      type="number"
      InputProps={{
        inputProps: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
        },
      }}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

